# I am trying to execute it but it throws error of 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This function is not implemented by this driver.'

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, prepared-statement

I have tried calling the function but it gives me errors always.
My code is below

```
$name = 'Devrishi Pandey';
$return_message = prepared_insert($pdo, 'my_table', ['name' => $name]);
function prepared_insert($pdo, $table, $data) {
    $keys = array_keys($data);
    $fields = implode(",", $keys);
    $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($keys) - 1) . '?';
    try{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)";
        $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $pdo->execute($data);
        return $pdo->lastInsertId();
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        return $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you echo out your `$sql` to see what it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) function is for a PDOStatement, not connection. You need to assign the prepared statement to a variable then execute on that.

```
$name = 'Devrishi Pandey';
$return_message = prepared_insert($pdo, 'my_table', ['name' => $name]);
function prepared_insert($pdo, $table, $data) {
    $keys = array_keys($data);
    $fields = implode(",", $keys);
    $placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($keys) - 1) . '?';
    try{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($data);
        return $pdo->lastInsertId();
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        return $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```